# Is it possible to use old RAM on new MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

My current MacBook Pro, a early-2013 13" i5, is getting very slow and I therefore want to buy a new one. However, I want to wait until the next generation comes out. In the meantime I will change the RAM from 4GB to 16GB.

My questions is if the RAM for the early 2013 macbook will work in the new MacBook Pro?

Comment: If your MacBook's performance has significantly degraded you may find doing some basic maintenance restores its usability. Clearing old caches out etc. using utlities like Onyx can work wonders. Disk maintenance is pretty much essential as this can have a significant effect on system speed. DiskWarrior is still my go-to utility for this. Doing a clean OS X installation can clear out a load of clutter if you've installed loads of software you rarely/never use. A 2013 Mac certainly shouldn't be slow enough to need a replacement if it's been looked after...

Answer (score 1):

I'll make it quick for you : MacBook Pro and MacBook Air have the ram now soldered to the main board.

You won't be able to upgrade the ram on the new MacBooks.